# Get combobox value in Java swing

Tags: java, swing

I need to get the integer value of the combobox in Swing.

I have set an integer value as id for the combobox.I tried combobox.getSelectedItem() and combobox.getSelectedIndex() but it cant get the int value.

Below is my code:

```
CommonBean commonBean[]=new CommonBean[commonResponse.getCommonBean().length+1];         
         for(int i=0;i<commonResponse.getCommonBean().length;i++)
         {
             commonBean[i] = new CommonBean("--Please select a project--", 0);
             commonBean[i+1] = new CommonBean(commonResponse.getCommonBean()[i].getProjectName(), commonResponse.getCommonBean()[i].getProjectId());
         }

JComboBox combobox= new JComboBox(commonBean);


public CommonBean(String projectName,int projectId) {       
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.projectId = projectId;

    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Your update is incomplete. What is the type of `projectId`, for example?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Method `Object JComboBox.getSelectedItem()` returns a value that is wrapped by `Object` type so you have to cast it accordingly.

Syntax:

```
YourType varName = (YourType)comboBox.getSelectedItem();`
String value = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: I am getting only a string value when i use the above.(i.e the name the user sees in the combobox).

Comment: Based on the update, it looks like `YourType` is `CommonBean`, from which `projectId` may be obtained.

Comment: no sence to put String as Items and then to parse, put there number instance directly ...

Answer (score 7):

If the string is empty, `comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()` will give a `NullPointerException`. So better to typecast by `(String)`.