# Calculate combo box values

Tags: string, combobox

Tried this nothing happened. [Get combobox value in Java swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999560/get-combobox-value-in-java-swing)

So tried this

```
float[] cboDevice = new float[2]; 
cboDevice[0] = 250;
cboDevice[1]= 350; 
float [] cboRam = new float[4];
cboRam[0] = 25; cboRam[1]= 50; 
cboRam[2] = 75; cboRam[3]= 100; 
float [] cboHdd = new float[6]; 
cboHdd[0] = 110;
cboHdd[1]= 120;
cboHdd[2] = 130;
cboHdd[3]= 140; 
cboHdd[4]= 150;
cboHdd[5]= 160;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners

---

```
String value1 = (String) cboDevice.getSelectedItem(); 
String value2 = (String) cboRam.getSelectedItem(); 
String value3 = (String) cboHdd.getSelectedItem();
String value4 = (String) cboScreen.getSelectedItem();
```

no such luck.

Can anyone let me know how to use the values in my combo box in a calculation? This problem is as easy as it sounds, got the boxes up and running I just can't do anything when the combo is selected.

Peace.

Comment: Post your code not links , Quality of question is inversely proportional to time to get answer .

Comment: float[] cboDevice = new float[2];
        cboDevice[0] = 250;
        cboDevice[1]= 350;
        float [] cboRam = new float[4];
        cboRam[0] = 25;
        cboRam[1]= 50;
        cboRam[2] = 75;
        cboRam[3]= 100;
        float [] cboHdd = new float[6];
        cboHdd[0] = 110;
        cboHdd[1]= 120;
        cboHdd[2] = 130;
        cboHdd[3]= 140;
        cboHdd[4]= 150;
        cboHdd[5]= 160;

Comment: String value1 = (String) cboDevice.getSelectedItem();
   String value2 = (String) cboRam.getSelectedItem();
   String value3 = (String) cboHdd.getSelectedItem();
   String value4 = (String) cboScreen.getSelectedItem();