# How to make string get elements from an array based on the combobox array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, jcombobox

I miss something and I will appreciate your help
I have this array for a combobox

```
String array [] = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
```

and I have this for loop to run all over the array

```
for(String s: array) {
    if(s.equals(array[0]) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Now what I need is that, I need the "do something" to happen to each element in the array only when the element is selected by the combobox, my array is so long and I can't write if statement for each element in the array.

What I want is something like that

```
for(String s : array) { 
  if(s equals the array elements) {
      substring the first index of each element
      print s
      so result let's say will be like this
      a ----> if only element a is selected
      b ----> if only element b is seleceted
      etc ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I think what you need is an event listener for the combobox and then match the value of that combobox against your array in an if statement, then `do something` with it. I'm not sure in what context you're talking about "combobox" whether this is Android or JavaFX or something.

Comment: @px06
thank you, yes indeed I'm using as ItelmListener for this, but I miss something to make my if statement works fine.
I use normal Java in Eclipse to do this

Comment: So, you are referring to something like JCombobox?

Comment: Please expand and improve your question. You know how to do for loops, you know how to do if blocks -- so what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: If this is using Java Swing then here is sort of a duplicate question on how to get the selected value of a combobox, but as the question and tags are so vague I can't be sure what library OP is using. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999560/get-combobox-value-in-java-swing

Comment: To all of you, thank you a lot, I've figured out what I needed to do

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem, thank you all and sorry for disturbing you

```
for(String s: arrar) {
  if(combobox.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) {
     do something;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As **px06** said, you might want to add an event listener on your Combobox and then handle item selection. 
Here is code snippet for what you are looking for:

```
String[] array = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(array);
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JComboBox<String> combo = (JComboBox<String>) event.getSource();
        String selectedItem = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();

        if (selectedItem.equals("<some-choice>")) {
            //do something
        } else if (selectedItem.equals("<some-other-choice>")) {
            //do something else...
        }
    }
});
```

However I do not see how you can escape checking which item was selected if you want to do something specific based on selection.

I hope this helps.